# Attribute-based access control with database

Tags: database, authorization, access-control, abac

I work for a software house and I'm looking for a way to authenticate database access as follow:

1. Someone whose personal data are stored in a table needs to read his
   personal row and he has the right to access the table.
2. Once the requested row has been retrieved, I need an external check
   which ensures he has the right to read that specific row, checking
   some table's fields which are contained in the same row.

It seems to me that the attribute-based access control is what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure. Can you confirm if it's able to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [ABAC](https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/) (the model) can do that. However, the check would typically happen before you get access to the data - and that's better actually (it avoids retrieving data).

ABAC gives you two things:

- a policy language to express what can and cannot happen. For instance

> A user can view a record they own but not the credit card field

- a request / response scheme or how to enforce the policies.

In the case of data-centric access control, policies are transformed into SQL filters. For instance, you would go from:

- SELECT * FROM transactions;

to

- SELECT amount, owner, CASE WHEN (0=1) THEN CREDITCARD ELSE 'xxxx' FROM transactions WHERE owner = 'Alice'

This is called dynamic data filtering and dynamic data masking. Some database vendors have had that capability e.g. Oracle and VPD or MySQL and FGAC. Lately the trend is to outsource this type of behavior to tools like Informatica DDM or [Axiomatics ADAF MD](https://www.axiomatics.com/product/axiomatics-data-access-filter-adaf/) (which is where I work).